# Inserting XML into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Given this XML:

```
<Documents>
    <Batch BatchID = "1" BatchName = "Fred Flintstone">
        <DocCollection>
            <Document DocumentID = "269" KeyData = "" />
            <Document DocumentID = "6"   KeyData = "" />
            <Document DocumentID = "299" KeyData = ""     ImageFile="Test.TIF" />
        </DocCollection>    
    </Batch>    
    <Batch BatchID = "2" BatchName = "Barney Rubble">
        <DocCollection>
            <Document DocumentID = "269" KeyData = "" />
            <Document DocumentID = "6"   KeyData = "" />
        </DocCollection>
    </Batch>
</Documents>
```

I need to insert it into a table in SQL Server in this format:

```
BatchID   BatchName           DocumentID
1         Fred Flintstone     269
1         Fred Flintstone     6
1         Fred Flintstone     299
2         Barney Rubble       269
2         Barney Rubble       6
```

This SQL:

```
   SELECT
        XTbl.XCol.value('./@BatchID','int') AS BatchID,
        XTbl.XCol.value('./@BatchName','varchar(100)') AS BatchName,
        XTbl.XCol.value('DocCollection[1]/DocumentID[1]','int') AS DocumentID
   FROM @Data.nodes('/Documents/Batch') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

gets me this result:

```
BatchID BatchName       DocumentID
1       Fred Flintstone NULL
2       Barney Rubble   NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, can someone recommend a good tutorial for XML in SQL Server?

Thanks

Carl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close.

Using a wildcard and a CROSS APPLY, you can generate multiple records.

Changed alias to **lvl1** and **lvl2** to better illustrate.

```
Declare @XML xml = '
<Documents>
    <Batch BatchID = "1" BatchName = "Fred Flintstone">
        <DocCollection>
            <Document DocumentID = "269" KeyData = "" />
            <Document DocumentID = "6"   KeyData = "" />
            <Document DocumentID = "299" KeyData = ""     ImageFile="Test.TIF" />
        </DocCollection>    
    </Batch>    
    <Batch BatchID = "2" BatchName = "Barney Rubble">
        <DocCollection>
            <Document DocumentID = "269" KeyData = "" />
            <Document DocumentID = "6"   KeyData = "" />
        </DocCollection>
    </Batch>
</Documents>
'

Select BatchID    = lvl1.n.value('@BatchID','int') 
      ,BatchName  = lvl1.n.value('@BatchName','varchar(50)') 
      ,DocumentID = lvl2.n.value('@DocumentID','int') 
 From  @XML.nodes('Documents/Batch') lvl1(n)
 Cross Apply lvl1.n.nodes('DocCollection/Document') lvl2(n)
```

**Returns**

```
BatchID BatchName       DocumentID
1       Fred Flintstone 269
1       Fred Flintstone 6
1       Fred Flintstone 299
2       Barney Rubble   269
2       Barney Rubble   6
```

Comment: Good solution, +1 from my side, but why the `*` in the first `.nodes()`?

Comment: @Shnugo Now that you mention it, /Batch would be safer/more specific. Or were you thinking something else?

Comment: No, just to avoid errors, if there might be more nodes with other names...

Comment: @Shnugo Updated, but the Cross Apply would still target DocCollection/Document.   Just for fun I added <MiscOther><Document DocumentID = "269" KeyData = "" /></MiscOther>  ... within a Batch and as a peer

Comment: Well, this is sophisticated :-D Tried to enclose your test `<Document>` with `<DocCollcetion>`?